# Gridster remove widget and cookie

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться, использую gridster нормально все работает с изменением размера виджета и их сохранении разобрался, но не могу понять как сохранить cookie при удалении виджета

```
var gridster;
$(function() {
gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
widget_margins: [10, 10],
widget_base_dimensions: [150, 120],
autogrow_cols: true,
resize: {
        enabled: true
    },
serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
    return {
    id: wgd.el[0].id,
    col: wgd.col,
    row: wgd.row,
    size_y: wgd.size_y,
    size_x: wgd.size_x          
    }
},
draggable: {
    stop: function(event, ui) {
    var positions = JSON.stringify(gridster.serialize());
    console.log(positions);
    if (ui.position.left >433 ) gridster.remove_widget(ui.$helper[0]);
    $.cookie("grid-data", positions, { expires : 7 });
    }
}

      }).data('gridster');    
});

if ($.cookie("grid-data") !== null) {
    var scorepos = JSON.parse($.cookie("grid-data"));   
}
for (var i = 0; i < scorepos.length; i++){
    var position = scorepos[i];
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("data-row",position.row);
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("data-col",position.col);
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("data-sizex",position.size_x);
    list.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].setAttribute("data-sizey",position.size_y);
}
```